# Output double quotes and variable

Tags: shell-script, quoting, letsencrypt, certbot

I'm writing a script to automate Let's Encrypt in PowerDNS,(this is a simple bash shell script to be run on debian)

Certbot runs and calls the script, feeding to it the variable: 
$CERTBOT_VALIDATION

I read a thread already [here](https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/issues/6087) which shows the need for `'"content"'` – notice the single quote `'` and the double quote `"`. (i've tried this in a different iteration of the code to no avail)
 I'm struggling to output the expanded variable inside quotes, here is one way i tried:

```
pdnsutil add-record Example.com _acme-challenge txt 120 "\"%s\""  "$CERTBOT_VALIDATION"
```

However, to output that from bash, I must add a `\` before the `"`.

I want the output command to be as follows:

```
 pdnsutil add-record Example.com _acme-challenge txt 120 "content"
```

What is the best way to do this?

whatever is currently being output is erroring with:

```
Error: Parsing record content (try 'pdnsutil check-zone'): Data field in DNS should start with quote (") at position 0 of ''yXtgt_2vlnrF7j2V-eTJZuSjXbswsGN97TQ0Zp3IynM''
```

Comment: What is wrong with escaping double quotes ... ?

Comment: What language is your script?

Comment: Quoting is hard, but I feel that you’re making it harder than you need to. I also feel that you’re not telling us everything — maybe because you think it’s too obvious? Are you trying to run a command, or are you writing a script whose job is to create a second script? You say, “I want the output command to be as follows”, and show a line that doesn’t have any single quotes in it — so why are you even talking about single quotes? It looks like you have a solution; why isn’t it good enough? What do you need help with?

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

i'll provide an update as a potential answer for anyone who comes across this in the future.

when running the certbot command:

```
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --manual-auth-hook /etc/letsencrypt/customScripts/authenticator.sh -d *.example.com --dry-run
```

the script authenticator.sh is now:

```
#!/bin/bash
new='"'
new2=$new$CERTBOT_VALIDATION$new
pdnsutil add-record example.com _acme-challenge txt 120 $new2
echo $new2 > output.log
# Sleep to make sure the change has time to propagate over to DNS
sleep 25
```

this works, concatenating the variables as strings to add the double quotes.
output.log shows the variable was

```
cat output.log 
"RipQQbHO5pG95nzJjouCgTXJMrGTbLKQ5XsV5Zgn7uI"
```

and certbot reports:

```
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --manual-auth-hook /etc/letsencrypt/customScripts/authenticator.sh -d *.example.com --dry-run
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator manual, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
dns-01 challenge for example.com

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
NOTE: The IP of this machine will be publicly logged as having requested this
certificate. If you're running certbot in manual mode on a machine that is not
your server, please ensure you're okay with that.

Are you OK with your IP being logged?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
(Y)es/(N)o: y
Output from authenticator.sh:
RipQQbHO5pG95nzJjouCgTXJMrGTbLKQ5XsV5Zgn7uI
New rrset:
_acme-challenge.example.com. IN TXT 120 "RipQQbHO5pG95nzJjouCgTXJMrGTbLKQ5XsV5Zgn7uI"

Error output from authenticator.sh:
Apr 05 10:51:41 Reading random entropy from '/dev/urandom'
Apr 05 10:51:41 gmysql Connection successful. Connected to database 'pdns' on '127.0.0.1'.
Apr 05 10:51:41 gmysql Connection successful. Connected to database 'pdns' on '127.0.0.1'.

Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The dry run was successful.
```

so this seems to have solved it.